# binary search for multiple values

Tags: python, search, numpy, binary, binary-search-tree

Hi i have a python related question,

I have a sorted Numpy array which i have to find the index of certain values quickly, I've been using a binary search so far but the issue im having is that there is numerous entry's of the same value and i have to find the index of all the values. is there a way to modify the binary search to find the all?
current code is

```
def binarySearch(alist,item,con_array,element):
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(alist)//2
        if alist[midpoint]==item:            
            for l in range(len(alist)):
                if alist[l] == item:
                    n_array.append(con_array[l])
            return True                   
        else:
            if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item,con_array[:midpoint],i)
            else:
                return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item,con_array[midpoint+1:],i)
```

as you can see I've tried to incorporate this by simply searching the shortened array but this still cuts out some of the values

Comment: current code doesn't run, says indentation is broken

Comment: How many values do you need to find? If you need find many values, binary search might not be the best option.

Comment: as much as 15 not less than 4 in an array with about 1,000,000 entrys

Answer (score 5):

Binary search can easily be adapted to find the first value greater than the key, so that with two searches you've found the range of values equal to the key. NumPy has actually already implemented that for you:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7])
>>> left = np.searchsorted(a, 2, side='left')
>>> right = np.searchsorted(a, 2, side='right')
>>> a[left:right]
array([2, 2, 2])
```

For very large arrays, it might be slightly more efficient to perform the second search on `a[left:]`:

```
>>> right = left + np.searchsorted(a[left:], 2, side='right')
>>> a[left:right]
array([2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: HI thanks for your response this looks interesting but i is the indexes of the values im looking for is there anyways to modify it to output the indexs?

Comment: that method is working nicely the only issue is its quite slow in compression to my other method (all be it mine doesn't work properly) speed is a major factor for this application

Comment: @user2957178 I find that hard to believe. Do you have benchmark figures?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting binary search to do that is an very educational exercise, and when I teach algorithms I always suggest to my students that they try it. If you just want to get it done, `numpy` already has a function that does what you want:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1])
np.where(a==1)
```

which outputs

```
(array([0, 3, 6, 7]),)
```

Comment: Even on this tiny amount of data, calling `np.searchsorted` twice is faster than `np.where` (not counting the cost of sorting). At 10000 elements, it's an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't think of `searchsorted`

Comment: That's not a binary search, it's a linear search. Which is why np.where is so much slower.